# Error : 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: java

java program is not running on my windows 10 pc.

```
C:\Users\Antony>set path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin

C:\Users\Antony>cd Desktop

C:\Users\Antony\Desktop>javac helloworld.java
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Antony\Desktop>

environment path =C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin
```

C:\Users\

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode, sharing)
```

still showing same error

Comment: javac is located in the jdk folder; not the jre folder. Have you installed jdk?

Comment: @n8te I have installed..please check question , i have edited

Comment: See my answer below. You have to now add jdk to your path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Compiler (javac) is installed with the Java Development Kit (jdk), not the Java Runtime Environment (jre)

If you have not already done so, go to the [Oracle website](http://oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and look for the JDK version that you need.

After installing it, set the path to the following:

```
set path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin
```

(assuming you're going to install the equivalent architecture/version of jdk that you installed of jre above)