# How to detect java by cmd, after installing it, without restarting the PC in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, java

When I install Java, at the end of the installation, it does not detect it on my system:

```
C:\Windows\system32>where java
INFO: No file could be found for the given patterns.
```

and

```
C:\Windows\system32>java -version
"java" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
executable program or batch file.
```

[image]

Only, when I restart the PC, then it does detect it

[image]

Question: what command should I use by cmd to detect the presence of java installed (any version), without restarting the PC?

PD: tested on windows 10 pro x64 21h2

**Update:**

I have modified [Carsten.R's solution](https://superuser.com/a/1740061/886205):

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s /f *jre* >nul 2>&1 & IF %errorlevel% == 0 (echo OK) else (echo FAIL)
```

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1315592/error-javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) should answer your question.

Comment: My [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67526703/12349734) will solve your problem. You have to add the `java home` environment variable

Comment: Update question

Comment: This is a simple problem.  Java is not in your path in the first instance, it is in the second.  `where java` has NOTHING to do with anything but your path not getting refreshed.  When you installed Java, were you in the same command  window as when you tried to find it?  Cmd.exe probably only needs a restart.  Since you can KNOW where they put Java.exe have you tried simply adding it to your path until the restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi see my batch file below. That works before reboot, it extracts the install path from the registry and adds it to the search path of the current cmd process.

1. Find the JAVA HOME with req query
2. Split REG_SZ req query
3. Trim the result
4. Add to the process search path
5. Use WHERE or JAVA as you like

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /V JAVA_HOME  ^|findstr /ri "REG_SZ"') do SET RESULT=%%~a
SET "RESULT=%RESULT:* REG_SZ =%"
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("%RESULT%") do set TRIMRESULT=%%a
echo ---%TRIMRESULT%---
SET PATH=%PATH%;%TRIMRESULT%

where java
pause
REM ALTERNATIVE REG KEY
REM reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /S /f *jdk-*
```

By the way the newer OpenJDK 17 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/download , works exactly as you would like. No need of fancy stuff.

If you want to test if something is install in windows querying the uninstall reg keys are the right way. It can be usefull for other applications too.

The example is made with the Microsoft package reg keys can vary base on the entry's, but I am sure you can adopt it easily.

Here an example for jre-8u341-windows-x64.exe

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s /f *jre*  ^|findstr /ri "REG_SZ"') do SET RESULT=%%~a
echo 1 ---%RESULT%---
pause
SET "RESULT=%RESULT:* REG_SZ =%"
echo 2 ---%RESULT%---
pause
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("%RESULT%") do set TRIMRESULT=%%a
echo 3 ---%TRIMRESULT%---
pause
SET PATH=%PATH%;%TRIMRESULT%

where java

pause
```

Comment: i tried your batch and it doesn't do what it's supposed to (tested on windows 10 21h2 with jre-8u341-windows-x64.exe installed)

Comment: Added an example for jre-8u341-windows-x64.exe there isn't much difference to the first post just some other string and switches in the reg query.

Comment: I already tried your script. You should check the output. Lots of breaks. In the end it does not find the patterns. Take your time. Do tests. It should work for any version of java

Comment: I did test (with installed java) both scripts on windows 10, what return do you get when you enter     reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s /f \*jre\*     in cmd.

Comment: the script has an error. Ends with "no files could be found for the given patterns". I could simplify it. I see redundancy. Thanks

Comment: I have modified your solution in one line and posted it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command line to find the file "java.exe"

```
cd C:\ & dir /s /b java.exe
```

It assume that Java is installed in C drive. Otherwise, you can change the drive letter in the command.

If you want to iterate over each drive, and stop directly once a result is found, you can use this powershell command :

```
$(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem' |%{ gci -Recurse $_.Root |?{$_.Name -eq "Java.exe"} | Select -First 1}).FullName
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort. The command is good, but it doesn't terminate and is limited to c:

Comment: @acgbox Edit with a new powershell command respecting these requirements.

Comment: please no powershell. Only cmd (batch)